# Can't use `local-unset-key` in emacs to remove keybindings in org mode

Tags: emacs, hook, key-bindings

I want to remove the key binding about "C-j" under org mode, then I am using "local-key-unset" to do it, but when I go to org-mode, the key binding is not removed.

My code is as below:

```lisp
 (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'(lambda () (local-unset-key (kdb "C-j"))))
```

the `org-mode-hook` value is

```
Value: ((lambda nil (local-unset-key (kdb "C-j"))) #[0 "\300\301\302\303\304$\207" [add-hook change-major-mode-hook org-fold-show-all append local] 5] #[0 "\300\301\302\303\304$\207" [add-hook change-major-mode-hook org-babel-show-result-all append local] 5] org-babel-result-hide-spec org-babel-hide-all-hashes #[0 "\301\211\207" [imenu-create-index-function org-imenu-get-tree] 2] (lambda nil (progn (company-mode -1) (company-box-mode -1))) (lambda nil (set (make-local-variable 'line-spacing) 0.5)) (lambda nil (keymap-local-set (kbd "C-z") 'shell)))
```

when in the org mode, I use `C-h k` to find the `C-j` bindings, its result:

```
C-j runs the command org-return-and-maybe-indent (found in
org-mode-map)
```

I try to use `C-j` to replace `C-x`, I use this code

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") ctl-x-map)
```

It worked very well. but when in the org mode, it seems to be shadowed by the major org-mode-map. I hope I can remove the `C-j` to unshadowed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named function `kbd` wrong, as **`kdb`**:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'(lambda () (local-unset-key (kdb "C-j"))))
```

When the hook function is invoked it in fact raises an error, such as this:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function kdb)
```

And when a hook function raises an error it's removed from the hook, so you see this error only the first time.

Replace `kdb` with `kbd` and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I'm very sorry for wasting your time with my spelling mistakes!

Comment: Actually, I did spend a while trying to figure out what was going on. ;-) But it wasn't time wasted. `kbd` is short but easily mistyped.

Comment: I just filed [bug #65891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=65891), to see if we can't get a more useful error msg for this kind of thing.